# Power Pivot To Many Dates

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot

Hope you are well!
I have two tables with a relationship through PowerPivot. To keep it simpler than the actual data, imagine one table contains information about sales representatives (name and target sales level) and one contains the actual sales data (monthly sales by sales rep). Assume the sales reps have target sales levels which do not change over time, but that different sales reps started working for the company at different times.

Sample Table 1

[image: Sales Rep Information]

Sample Table 2

[image]

I want to show in individual graphs the actual performance against the target for each sales rep. However, you'll see that there isn't any data for John for January, as he just joined in February.

Thus, when I plot this, using a pivot table, the date scale starts in January 2020 for John too, where you then just see the target and no actual sales data. What can I do, so that the x-axis starts at the first date for each graph in which there is available data?